# React Native: How can I create a new Text component from a function?

Tags: javascript, ios, react-native

I want to create a new Text Component through a function called by pressing a button.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, Button } from 'react-native';

export default class App extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.clicks = 0;
  }

  addText() {
    return (
      // something to add a new Text component to the View
    )
  }

  ButtonPress() {
    this.clicks++;
    if (this.clicks > 0 && this.clicks % 20 == 0) {
      this.addText();
    }
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Button
          title="Click me"
          onPress={this.ButtonPress.bind(this)}
        />
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

I know it's possible by making an arrow function in the `onPress` from the button, but I want to do it exclusively from a function.
Is it possible? If so, how?
Any help is appreciated.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Use conditional rendering for the Text.
`condition && <Text>{text}</Text>`

### Example

```
    import React, { Component } from 'react'
    import { Text, View, Button } from 'react-native'
    
    export default class index extends Component {
        state={
            text: '',
            textVisible: false
        }

        toggle=()=>{
            const { textVisible } = this.state
            this.setState({textVisible: !textVisible, text: 'Add some text here..'})
        }
        render() {
            const { text, textVisible } = this.state
            return (
                <View style={styles.container}>
                    {textVisible&&<Text>{text}</Text>}
                    <Button title='Toggle' onPress={this.toggle} />
                </View>
            )
        }
    }
```

Comment: That's the way to go